# How SQL Server detects a record internally?

Tags: sql-server, database-internals

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889855/identity-column-in-sql-server) SO post where the author (stack programmer) states

> SQL server uses the identity column as the key value to refer to a
>   particular row. So only a single identity column can be created.

He also mentioned that

> Also if no identity columns are explicitly stated, Sql server
>   internally stores a separate column which contains key value for each
>   row.

Could anyone explain the two points(specially the second one) in  more details?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could anyone explain the two points(specially the second one) in more details?

I hope not, since they are both **wrong**. In SQL Server rows are identified by keys (in B-trees) or by row ids (in heaps). Non-unique clustered indexes have an internal uniqueifier column. The fact that often times an IDENTITY type column is also used as a primary key is orthogonal to the question.

Do not base your knowledge on stuff from posts on forums, including StackOverflow, and including this very post. A good source is the official documentation, eg. [Tables and Index Data Structures Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180978%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Read a good book, like the [SQL Server Internals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735658560) series.